# Undefined reference to symbol __cxa_free_exception@@CXXABI_1.3

Tags: clang

Using `clang` to link a program fails like this:

> /usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld: stackoverflow.o: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_free_exception@@CXXABI_1.3'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like with gcc, you have to use clang++ to link C++ programs